# Errors using FMXLinux on CentOS_7 1908

Tags: linux, delphi, centos, delphi-10.3-rio

```
[DCC Error] E2597 C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lrtlhelper_PIC
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lrtlhelper
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\20.0\bin\ld-linux.exe: error: cannot find -lpcre_PIC
```

When compiling, I have this error. Has anyone seen this and know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

in terminal run the following commands:

```
sudo yum install qt4-devel
sudo yum install gcc-c++.x86_64
```

or

```
sudo yum glibc-static
sudo yum install glibc-devel
sudo yum install zlib-devel
```

or if not enough

```
sudo yum install compat-libstdc++-33
sudo yum install compat-gcc-44-c++
```

Then update the local file cache for Linux SDK in Delphi->Options/Deployment/SDK Manager

Stefanos

Comment: thanks for answering. had installed radstudio with win32 and linux 64, uninstalled, and installed it completely with the tools and started to work